# arp update not working as expected

Tags: switch, arp

I have a simple network setup as follows (both switches are layer 3, and switch 1 is also a router to reach outside network):
[image]

I need to move an IP address from PC A to PC B (following a PC failure).  The network above is attached to eth1 on both PC's.  (eth0 is connected to an unrelated network).

After failover, I issue this command from PC B:

```
arping -U -I eth1 -c 5 172.31.253.4
ARPING 172.31.253.4 from 172.31.253.4 eth1
Sent 5 probes (5 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s)
```

As you can see no responses are received.  If I issue ifconfig on PC B I can confirm the NIC is up and running:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    ether 00:50:56:a5:19:72  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 27854916  bytes 15728132541 (14.6 GiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 91  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 19645321  bytes 2992871301 (2.7 GiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.31.253.4  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.31.253.255
    ether 00:0c:29:1e:b0:1d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 13397  bytes 7034331 (6.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 11998  bytes 6102989 (5.8 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

1. Why is the ARP update (arping) failing?  (no responses)
2. How should I notify switch 1 (router) that the path to the old IP has changed?   (and arping along from PC A won't reach switch 1 since it's 2 hops away)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A switch will update its MAC address table from any frame it receives on a port. Switches aren't interested in IP, or any other layer-3, addresses, only layer-2 (MAC) addresses. ARP is a host protocol to resolve a layer-3 address to a layer-2 address.

Since the layer-2 addresses of the PCs aren't changing, the switches are unaffected by the change in IP address.

You can clear the ARP cache on the router. It will eventually time out anyway, probably during the time it takes you to notice that PC A is down and move the IP address to PC B.

You are trying to arping you own address, and you don't get a reply. If you arping the gateway address, you should get a reply.

**Edit**:

First, a layer-3 switch is primarily a layer-2 switch. The layer-3 router of the switch is separate from the layer-2 switch part, connected to the layer-2 switch via (a) virtual interface(s), as if it was a separate external device. The router is only concerned with what are connected to its layer-3 interfaces, virtual, or physical.

Just as if it was a separate router, the router of the layer-3 switch maintains an ARP cache for a connection to a layer-2 network, but it only knows which layer-3 interface to which it should send traffic, not which particular layer-2 port to which an individual host is connected.

The layer-2 switch part is just like any other layer-2 switch, it maintains a MAC address table which tells it to which port a MAC address is connected, and it knows nothing about layer-3 addresses.

The router ARP cache and the MAC address table entries are temporal; they time out after a certain period of time. This time period may be configurable, depending on the switch model. The time period is probably much less than the amount of time it takes for you to notice that PC A is down, plus the amount of time it takes for you to configure PC B with the IP address from PC A.

The layer-2 part of the switch is the part concerned with the physical switch port to which PC B is connected, and it only cares about PC B's MAC address, which I doubt you changed when changing its IP address.

The router's ARP cache is only concerned with which MAC address should be related to the IP address, not the physical switch port to which PC A or B is connected. The ARP cache entry may be stale, but not for long, and probably not at all.

Hosts, including routers, are constantly timing out ARP cache entries when traffic isn't received from the IP addresses. Assigning the IP address to PC B will cause it to ARP for the router's MAC address when it needs to contact the router, and that will change the router's ARP cache entry for that IP address to point to PC B's MAC address.

**TL;DR**

In short, there is nothing you need to do to the switches when PC A is disabled, and you assign the address from PC A to PC B.

Comment: Both of the switches are layer 3 switches.  If traffic comes in from the outside world (top of graphic), how does switch 1 know whether to direct the traffic to 172.31.254.4 to the left or right branch?

Comment: Are the two PCs using the same network? If so, the switches are using layer-2. Layer-3 switches are first layer-2 switches. The layer-3 part is only for routing between networks.

Comment: In this case switch 1 actually routes between networks.

Comment: I may be missing something theoretical here.  Doesn't a switch track which MAC is on which port using the ARP cache?  (Isn't that how it knows where to direct traffic)?

Comment: No, it does not. A switch maintains a MAC address table to track a MAC address to a particular port. An ARP cache is for hosts which need to resolve a layer-3 address into a layer-2 address. Switches don't care about layer-3 addresses. A host will encapsulate a layer-3 packet in a layer-2 frame, and the switch will switch the traffic based on the layer-2 destination address in the layer-2 frame header. Switches can carry a variety of layer-3 packets (e.g. IPv4, IPX, IPv6), each of which have different layer-3 addressing.

Comment: "_In this case switch 1 actually routes between networks._" If PC A and PC B are on different networks, You cannot use the network address from PC A on PC B since PC B would then have an address for a different network than the network on which it is. If they are on the same network, then the layer-2 communication is unaffected. The switch learns the layer-2 address and port of each PC when any frame from a PC comes into a switch port.

Comment: I didn't mean pc A and pc B are on different networks - only that switch 1 routes to other networks as well.   I will try to clarify my question above.

Comment: On the same network, traffic is switched at layer-2, and layer-2 (MAC) addresses are all the switches care about. I doubt you changed the PC MAC address when you changed the IP address. The switches will build their MAC address tables as frames come into the switch ports. Only layer-3 devices have ARP caches and care about the layer-3 to layer-2 resolution (ARP). At layer-2, switches are transparent.

Comment: Sorry if I'm having trouble expressing this correctly.  Since Switch 1 is a router and a switch, it must track IP (layer 3) per port, to ensure it send traffic down the right link.  (perhaps in a CAM table).  If I move the IP, how do I let switch 1 know?  arping?  ping?  etc...

Comment: You don't understand. The router is separate from the layer-2 switch in the switch, as if it were a separate device. The router has an ARP cache which tells it which MAC address to use for which IP address, but it doesn't relate it to a port; it simply builds a frame and gives it to the network (virtual) interface of the layer-2 part of the switch. The layer-2 part of the switch has a MAC address table to tell it which port has which MAC address. Both the ARP cache and the MAC address table entries time out. You should not need to do anything since they get dropped and rebuilt all the time.

Comment: @Telium, this behavior allows you to connect a new PC, with new MAC and IP addresses, to a switch, and it will just start working. You can then move that PC to a different switch or switch port in the same network, and it will continue to function. This is all handled automatically for you.

Comment: Ok - it's getting clearer.  So there is no need to update CAM tables in switches (since MAC's are not moving, only IP, and since they're on the same subnet they don't care about IP).  Only the router needs an ARP update.  Does that mean if PC A issued an ARPING, would it cross switches 1 and 2 (which are layer 3) and reach the router to update its arp cache?

Comment: See the edit to my answer. When PC B, with the former IP address of PC A, needs to contact the router, it will ARP the router's MAC address, and that will update the router's ARP cache, which, in all probability, has already timed out the ARP cache entry for that IP address, but it doesn't matter if it hasn't since the router's ARP cache will be updated by the ARP from PC B. That happens automatically.